# I'm unable to display hyperlink via a jsp function it displays my link as text

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, hyperlink

I have below function taking text as inputs and returning text with warning symbol in a box

```
function showErrorMessage3(textErrorMessage1, textErrorMessage2, textInputName) {
    console.log("showErrorMessage2, textErrorMessage1=[" + textErrorMessage1 + "], textErrorMessage2=["+ textErrorMessage2 +"], textInputName=[" + textInputName + "]");
    $('.error_txt_input dd').text(textErrorMessage1+'\n'+textErrorMessage2);
    $('.error_txt_input').css('display','block');
    $('.error_txt_input').addClass(textInputName + '_Error');
}
```

this code should display the URL being passed in TextErrorMessage1 as a hyperlink.
But it is instead displaying it as plain text.

Comment: post your error_txt_input from html

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `$('.error_txt_input dd')` is an `<a>` tag thus you can do this:

```
$('.error_txt_input dd').attr('href', textErrorMessage1);
```

if not then try this:

```
  $('.error_txt_input dd').wrap(function() {
       var link = $('<a/>');
       link.attr('href', textErrorMessage1);
       link.text(textErrorMessage1+'\n'+textErrorMessage2);
       return link;
    });
```